# String To bytes Error

Tags: javascript, bytes

I am trying to take user input strings and convert them to `bytes32` and `bytes5` for a contract built in Solidity 5.11, I tried 32 and 5 character long random strings respectively however they are not working, is there an inbuilt function for web3 to convert Strings to bytes (either 32 or 5) like `web3.utils.fromAscii` can be used to generate appropriate addresses from strings?

```
console.log(addressing("address");
console.log(bitify32("data"));
console.log(bitify5("key"));
function addressing(input) {
    let zeros = "0";  
    let input = web3.utils.fromAscii(input);
    if (input.length < 42) {
        let remainder = 32-input.length;
        for(let i = remainder-1; i > 0; i--) {
            zeros += "0";
        }
    }
    let inputZerod = input+zeros;
    return inputZerod;
}

function bytify32(input) {
    let zeros = "0";  
    let input = web3.utils.fromAscii(input);
    if (input.length < 32) {
        let remainder = 32-input.length;
        for(let i = remainder-1; i > 0; i--) {
            zeros += "0";
        }
    }
    let inputZerod = input+zeros;
    return inputZerod;
}
```

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

contract bytesTest{

  mapping(address => BytesStruct) testBytes; 

     struct BytesStruct{
        address stringAddress;
       bytes32 string1;
       bytes5 string2;
     }


     function getByteStrings(address _stringAddress) view public returns(bytes32, bytes5){
         return(testBytes[_stringAddress].string1, testBytes[_stringAddress].string2);
     }


  function addByteString(address _stringAddress, bytes32 _string1, bytes5 _string2) public{
    testBytes[_stringAddress].string1 = _string1;
    testBytes[_stringAddress].string2 = _string2;

  }

}
```

Comment: Please share your code in order to clarify your question.

Comment: I added my function, I just tried to make the string length match the byte size but it has not worked when trying to fill a 32 byte field in solidity 5.11

Comment: I don't get it. All you really need is `web3.utils.fromAscii(input)` (or in its more common name - `web3.utils.asciiToHex(input)`), which you are already using. Why all the padding?

Comment: I added a breakout of the smart contract for more context. I had to add padding to the addresses to get them to the appropriate length and I was doing the same for the bytes but with or without the padding it makes no difference

Comment: What do you even mean "generate appropriate addresses from strings"??? Converting an ASCII string into `bytes32` doesn't make an address out of it in any way. An address is 20 bytes, not 32!

Comment: It allowed me to add it as an address, but is a temporary measure.  I am more concerned with why when I convert tnx fromAscii I get "0x746e78" but it does not fufill requirements to be used as a byte5 value.

Comment: How about taking the input data as strings which represent addresses to begin with???

Comment: My apologies for any confusion, I am just trying to understand why the bytes32 and 5, need strings of exactly 5 or 32 bytes instead of that or less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am just trying to understand why the bytes32 and 5, need strings of length 66 and 11 respectively if each character is a byte

I'll explain for `bytes32`:

In order to send `bytes32` from web3.js to a smart-contract function, you need to provide a string which starts with `"0x"` followed by 64 hexadecimal characters.

Why 64? Because each character represents 4 bits (`f` - the highest - represents `1111`).

Since each byte consists of 8 bits, you need 64 hexadecimal characters in order to represent 32 bytes.

Including the `"0x"` prefix, you get a string of 66 characters.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, my padding for the Bytes was necessary, I was just off on the count, thank you.  I was under the impression in ASCII each character was eight bits not four, this helps alot with my confusion thank you very much.